# Phonejs dxlist drag down refresh in android not so smooth like ios

Tags: javascript, html, phonejs

I use the framework phonejs to develop a mobile project.

When I use the widget dxList enable the func drag down to refresh. It's not so smooth like ios. How to fix it ?

Can anybody give me some help...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the Emulator, I have seen this happen as well. The problem should be resolved on the physical devices. Just make sure useNativeScrolling is set to true in your dxList, you may also want to check your settings on your scrollView as well. If this does not resolve it, could better help you with an example code from your project showing the way your configuring your list. Hopefully this helps though.

Comment: I just make it after yesterday. As you said that was resolved on the physical devices. Thx for your help~ : )